# Use a Lookup/Index Match to Extract the X and Y coordinates from a grid in a google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a bunch of numbers on a cell grid in google spreadsheets. For example number 62 is at coordinates X: 120 and Y: 240. The Y Axis is in the A:AC Row and the X Axis is in the A:A Column. Each cell in those Axis has a coordinate number that goes up by an increment of 120. I have a list of the numbers that are on the cell grid off to the side and I want to extract the coordinates next to the list of numbers. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: link to a copy of your sheet.  It will be easier to understand what you need.

Comment: Here ya go. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/135H-yHO82XrjsTe21G8U8Hssa9EXTi_XEFopOlsy0c4/edit#gid=1359448583

Comment: Don't have permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For X in AG8:

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX($A$2:$A$89,MAX(IF($B$2:$AC$89=AF8,ROW($B$2:$AC$89)-ROW($B$2)+1))))
```

For Z in AH8:

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX($B$1:$AC$1,MAX(IF($B$2:$AC$89=AF8,COLUMN($B$2:$AC$89)-COLUMN($B$2)+1))))
```

Comment: @Viewtiful please mark as correct.  It is something only you can do.  Click the green check mark by the answer.